# Decode record while mapping a specific field

Tags: haskell

I have a record that looks like this:

```
data List a = List
    { list_count     :: Int
    , list__embedded :: [a]
    -- ^The actual data you’re looking for.
    }
    deriving (Show)
```

The `list__embedded` field is from an external API, where the embeds are actually an object:

```
{
  "count": 5,
  "_embedded": {
    "payments": [
        // payment records that derive FromJSON
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `_embedded` field is actually an object, but I'm only interested in the value of it.

I tried to solve it by writing the `FromJSON` implementation as following:

```
instance Aeson.FromJSON a => Aeson.FromJSON (List a) where
    parseJSON (Aeson.Object v) = List
        <$> Aeson.parseField v "count"
        <*> fmap HashMap.elems (Aeson.parseField v "_embedded")
    parseJSON invalid = Aeson.typeMismatch "Not a correct embed for a list" invalid
```

But I keep running into a type mismatch:

```
• Could not deduce (Aeson.FromJSONKey k0)
    arising from a use of ‘Aeson.parseField’
  from the context: Aeson.FromJSON a
    bound by the instance declaration
    at src/Mollie/API/Types.hs:366:10-52
  The type variable ‘k0’ is ambiguous
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Aeson.FromJSONKey Integer
      -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.2.4.0:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON’
    instance Aeson.FromJSONKey Text.Text
      -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.2.4.0:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON’
    instance Aeson.FromJSONKey Time.Day
      -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.2.4.0:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON’
    ...plus 14 others
    ...plus 14 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In the second argument of ‘fmap’, namely
    ‘(Aeson.parseField v "_embedded")’
  In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
    ‘fmap HashMap.elems (Aeson.parseField v "_embedded")’
  In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
    ‘List <$> Aeson.parseField v "count"
       <*> fmap HashMap.elems (Aeson.parseField v "_embedded")’
    |
369 |         <*> fmap HashMap.elems (Aeson.parseField v "_embedded")
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I not quite sure how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the key type for the `HashMap` is ambiguous.  Even though you don't use the keys, Haskell still needs to know the type so it can figure out what parser to instantiate for the `Aeson.parseField v "_embedded"` call.  You can help Haskell out by specializing a type signature for `elems`:

```
instance Aeson.FromJSON a => Aeson.FromJSON (List a) where
    parseJSON (Aeson.Object v) = List
        <$> Aeson.parseField v "count"
        <*> fmap elems (Aeson.parseField v "_embedded")
      where elems :: HashMap.HashMap Text.Text a -> [a]
            elems = HashMap.elems
    parseJSON invalid = Aeson.typeMismatch "Not a correct embed for a list" invalid
```

After this, I can do:

```
> Aeson.decode "{\"count\": 5, \"_embedded\": {\"payments\": [1,2,3,4]}}" 
          :: Maybe (List [Double])
Just (List {list_count = 5, list__embedded = [[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]]})
```

I'm not sure if you intended the payments list to be an *element* of `list__embedded` or not, but that should get you on the right track.

Comment: I can't believe it was "this simple" :D Thanks, that instantly fixed my issues.